# How can I combine animations in onFrame?

Tags: paperjs

My goal is to make the wave segments move from the bottom of the screen to the top, while animating the wave. The code I'm using to make the wave comes from paperjs.org:

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/#animating-path-segments

Ideally, I'd like to close the path with points that stay anchored to the bottom left and right of the viewport. This is so I can fill the wave with a solid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add points to your path before and after the for-loop that generates your evenly distributed segments:

```
path.add(new Point(0, 1) * view.size);

// Add 5 segment points to the path spread out
// over the width of the view:
for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
path.add(new Point(i / amount, 1) * view.size);
}

path.add(new Point(1, 1) * view.size);
```

This will give you points anchored to the bottom of your view. To account for the new segments, change the for loop in the onFrame function to read:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= amount+1; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answers the second part of my question of how to close the path. I was primarily curious about how I might animate the wave segments from the bottom of the page to the top, while they do their own wave animations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. Do you want the canvas and animation to cover the entire background of a page? What do you mean by "their own animations?"

Comment: The segments in the path that are added along the top are animated with `segment.point.y = sinus * height + 200;`. I'm trying to move those segments incrementally from the bottom of the page to the top so it will gradually cover the page entirely. I'm having a bit of trouble modifying that line of code to shift the y position of those segments up the page.

Comment: I'm trying to make one wave that starts off the bottom of the screen. Each point that has it's `point.y` should also gradually move toward the top of the page, while doing the existing wave animation simultaneously. Combining these two animations is the bit I'm hung up on.

Comment: Oh, so you want it to 'fill up' the screen? Every event object has an event.count property. You can use this to increment the height of the wave per frame. For example:  `segment.point.y = sinus * height + view.size.height - event.count;`

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes more sense.